# Client Linux: how to start the daemon from code?

Tags: java, linux, daemon, raspberry-pi2, alljoyn

I'm developing an linux client using alljoyn 15.04 (java)but i think is necessary start the alljoyn daemon before the client. is it right? how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should start the daemon before starting the client and in particular place the alljoyn deamon in a linux init script. Clone the openwrt_feed from here https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/core/openwrt_feed and use the file alljoyn/files/alljoyn.init as init script.

Comment: Use the command `git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/core/openwrt_feed` and it works

Answer (score 2):

You can use a built in routing node. Build AllJoyn Core using scons with BR=on to build with a bundled router. Then you need to link your program with the libajrouter.a static library and the liballjoyn.so shared library.

At the beginning of your program you will need to call AllJoynInit() followed by AllJoynRouterInit(), and at the end of the program the shutdown analogs in reverse order.

Since you're using the Java bindings there may be some differences but it should be possible.

If you do that you don't need the standalone daemon.